# Proyectos con Rosetta dejan de funcionar después de instalar Xcode 15

Tags: swift, xcode

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto que usa Xcode 14.1 con Rosseta implementado en el ( Se que no es lo ideal pero es un proyecto antiguo). El caso es que desde hace unos meses en mi departamento estamos teniendo el problema de que cada vez que nos instalamos Xcode 15, los proyectos que están en Xcode 14 o inferior que usan Roseta  dejan de funcionar y sale el siguiente mensaje.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La unica solucion que hemos encontrado ha sido resetear el ordenador y no instalar nunca mas Xcode 15, pero por cuestiones técnicas, tenemos que actualizarnos a esta versión de Xcode y volvemos a tener el mismo problema.

¿sabe alguien alguna solución que no implique resetear el ordenador?

Comment: Porqué necesitas Roseta para ejecutar Xcode? Si tienes una Mac M1 y una version de Xcode 15 al abrir proyectos antiguos, Xcode te muestra un mensaje para actualizar todo el proyecto con las nuevas configuraciones.

Comment: En la sección de simuladores, tienes alguna opción de seleccionar simuladores con Roseta o que sean x86?

Answer (score 0):

Cambiaron de lugar donde se activa.

Xcode -> Product (en el menu de arriba) -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> chequea 'Show Rosetta Destination'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]